# Angular2 memory consumption of a very large SPA

Tags: memory, angular, single-page-application

We are on the process of designing a new web application for a company's internal useage and the Front End will be created in MVC 6 and Angular2.
The project is quite large...analysis shows about 1000 forms.
Also, there is a finite amount of memory (we don't know the exact amount yet) that each terminal will have access to, as we will serve the pages through Citrix.

I understand that Angular2 is created with large apps in mind, but I identify some issues regarding such a large SPA:

1. Too large main module declarations object. 1000 forms in requirement analysis is twice that amount in components alone, any way to minimize this?
2. How much memory does Angular2 reserve for loaded components? Checking JS Heap memory. I can see that it reserves component prototypes in Heap, until routing to another page. I can find no information on memory management of Ang2, so any links or information would be more than welcome!
3. Is there an optimal amount of components per Module? One suggestion, is to break the SPA in several smaller ones each at their own MVC View.

My main concern is issue #2. Finite amount of memory is an issue on a project with so many components. 
The client would like a "dynamic tab like app", where he has access to any view at any time and be able to keep more that one such view open.
Splitting the app in more MVC Views, will make this feature difficult to implement.

tl;dr: Need info and guidelines on Angular2 memory consumption of very large SPAs!

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you think you need 1000 of anything, you actually need UX Designer :P To be serous, look into [Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html) and [NgModules](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) as @Günter sugested.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a problem with the number of forms. 
Components are just compiled to JavaScript and won't take up a lot of memory.

When components are instantiated they will take some additional space for the member variables that hold its state and some state maintained by Angular.

What usually causes problems is when a huge amount of components are displayed at the same time (even outside the visible area - instead of just showing what is necessary like virtual scrolling) because this takes a lot of CPU time and can make the browser slow and unresponsive.

The size of the modules by itself doesn't matter at all.
Modules where introduced to support lazy loading of parts of the application in combination with the router.
Therefore put parts of your application into lazy loaded modules that are not required on initial load. You can load parts of the application (lazy loaded modules) on demand when the user navigates to a specific route.